# Set unique DNS settings for one specific Linux process

Tags: linux, networking, dns, routing

I'm not sure if it can be done, but here's what I'm trying to do.
I am on a mac but trying to solve first for Linux, which is probably more general and might be easier.

- I want my system to be configured to use `8.8.8.8` as the general DNS for every usage.
- I want one process (Plex server, namely) to use another DNS server - namely, a DNS that allows me to pass region limitations on paid content subscriptions (hey at least I'm telling it straight). Let's call this DNS server `3.3.3.3`.

The reason for this is that I don't want to compromise the stability of my entire system in case the `3.3.3.3` DNS has issues. Yeah, I trust Google's DNS more.

Is it possible to do this kind of trickery? Or, are there other smart ways to make this work?

I have several other machines around and am willing to do routing trickery etc. as well, if anyone can think of a creative solution :)

Thanks a bunch!

Yonatan

Comment: If the Plex box's network config is static, just point its resolver at 3.3.3.3 and use 8.8.8.8 for the rest.  It's much more difficult if you're using DHCP for everything.  You'd have to set up address pools (such as described at http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf).  If all you have is the DHCPd server on your router, this probably can't be done and the only alternative is to switch to a static network configuration on the Plex box.

Comment: @joat thanks for the comment, in fact the "plex server" is running on my everyday laptop. since AFAIK plex channels are generated on the plex server, it seems I need to separate-by-process my laptop DNS usage (or other similar creative solution). And, static network is totally acceptable if helps.

Comment: Two DNS servers for processes in the same box?  "separate by process" isn't typical.  You'd need to hardcode the function into the Plex software.  About the only work-around that I can think of is to run the Plex server in VM.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. One other direction I might pursue is using a proxy of sorts (HTTP or better yet SOCKS). I admit that the question now makes me more curious in principle than in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose what you need is a 'container-like' technology.

Take a look at docker (Which is a very famous container technology now).

It runs the process in a separate container which may have different control group, resource namespaces etc.. and also, could have a different dns server configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Use Linux's mount namespace to override `/etc/resolv.conf` with what you want. Bubblewrap is a good tool to do that, without root.

```
bwrap --dev-bind / / --ro-bind-data {FD} /etc/resolv.conf
```

FD is the file descriptor that contains `nameserver {the-dns-you-need}`.

Remember to make system's DNS cache unaccessable for your process (Plex server) (eg. `bwrap --tmpfs /var/run/nscd/`)

Whole command:

```
bwrap --dev-bind / / --ro-bind-data {fd} /etc/resolv.conf --tmpfs /var/run/nscd/ sh -c "your command and arguments"
```

I wrote a bash script to do all the steps. [Here you are](https://github.com/garywill/proxc)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.
I'm leaving the container answer above as the accepted one, since it's probably more useful in the general case. But your answer hits my use case perfectly.